# realloc says Invalid next size

Tags: c, memory, realloc

Here is my code which should dynamically allocate memory for storing strings:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char **path = NULL;

    path = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *));

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
            path[i] = strdup("TEST");
            path = (char **) realloc(path, sizeof(char *));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
            printf("%s\n", path[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The above code breaks on the line where i have reallocated the memory.

According to me the the memory allocated to path on first malloc is as given below:

```
path -----> |   char *  | // path points to a character pointer which       inturn is pointing to nothing(Dangling).
```

So, at this point of time when the program ran the line:

```
path = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *));
```

path[0] is currently in bounds and we can store starting address of one and only one string at path[0] and path[1] should be out of bounds at this point of time.

So, when the very first time we entered the for loop where we are storing the address of string at path[i] we will be able to that as:

```
path[0] = strdup("TEST"); // is in bounds.
```

To store another string we need some more memory that path should be pointing.
So i did realloc in the line just below as:

```
path = (char **) realloc(path, (char *));
```

So, according to me path should look like this in memory as below:

```
path --------->|old char *|----->"TEST"
  |----------->|new char *|----->(Dangling) // Pointing Nowhere.
```

So, now path[1] is also in bounds and we should be able to use that memory location. So i can't figure out why i am getting this Segmentation fault when i run my code:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./dynamic: realloc(): invalid next size: 0x0000000000602010 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x75018)[0x7f743153e018]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7ae96)[0x7f7431543e96]
/lib64/libc.so.6(realloc+0xfa)[0x7f74315441aa]
./dynamic[0x40067f]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe6)[0x7f74314e7bc6]
./dynamic[0x400569]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 00:27 14459340                           /home/xpansat/c/basic/dynamic
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 00:27 14459340                           /home/xpansat/c/basic/dynamic
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 00:27 14459340                           /home/xpansat/c/basic/dynamic
00602000-00623000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f742c000000-7f742c021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f742c021000-7f7430000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f74312b2000-7f74312c8000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 173                        /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
7f74312c8000-7f74314c7000 ---p 00016000 fd:01 173                        /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
7f74314c7000-7f74314c8000 r--p 00015000 fd:01 173                        /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
7f74314c8000-7f74314c9000 rw-p 00016000 fd:01 173                        /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
7f74314c9000-7f743161d000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 27                         /lib64/libc-2.11.1.so
7f743161d000-7f743181d000 ---p 00154000 fd:01 27                         /lib64/libc-2.11.1.so
7f743181d000-7f7431821000 r--p 00154000 fd:01 27                         /lib64/libc-2.11.1.so
7f7431821000-7f7431822000 rw-p 00158000 fd:01 27                         /lib64/libc-2.11.1.so
7f7431822000-7f7431827000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f7431827000-7f7431846000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 20                         /lib64/ld-2.11.1.so
7f7431a14000-7f7431a17000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f7431a44000-7f7431a45000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f7431a45000-7f7431a46000 r--p 0001e000 fd:01 20                         /lib64/ld-2.11.1.so
7f7431a46000-7f7431a47000 rw-p 0001f000 fd:01 20                         /lib64/ld-2.11.1.so
7f7431a47000-7f7431a48000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fff62f8c000-7fff62fa2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff62fff000-7fff63000000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

I can't figure what i am doing wrong, because i was able to run my code if i changed my realloc line as below:

```
path = (char **) realloc(sizeof(char *)*8);
```

If is did that multiplication by 8 my code runs but i want to allocate exact memory i want, Any ideas why it is not working without that multiply by 8.

Comment: You have buffer overrun somewhere. You appear to be on Linux, so just run it under [Valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org) to find it.

Comment: `path = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *));`, then `path = (char **) realloc(path, sizeof(char *));` <- accessing `path[1]` in `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)` is undefined behaviour. You trample all over memory you have no right to access.

Comment: Note, that the `realloc` is totally pointless, because you request exactly the same size you allocated the array to initially. Remember, `sizeof(type)` is a compile-time constant!

Comment: Casting `malloc()/calloc()/realloc()` in C is not needed, even more it **not recommended**: http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/694576

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here

```
path = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *));
```

you are allocating a pointer to a pointer to `char`, that is space for one pointer to a C-"string".

Then here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
   path[i] = strdup("TEST");
   path = (char **) realloc(path, sizeof(char *));
}
```

you not only use one pointer to a C-"string" but reallocation for more does nothing more then just reallocate the same size as before, but infact you access as if you added memory for one more pointer in each iteration.

Doing so you overwrite memory not allocated (or alrerady in use by something else) and mess up the programs memory management.

A somewhat more straight forward approach to this would be:

```
  ...

  char ** path = NULL;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
  {
    path = realloc(path, (i+1) * sizeof(*path));
    path[i] = strdup("TEST");
  }

  ...
```

Comment: hello, actually I don't understand what did the OP want to do with this code but when I include a declaration for `strdup` the code works, i.e test is printed 5 times.Can you please explain it for me.thanks!

Comment: @PHIfounder C allows you do stuff that causes undefined behavior, like the original code here. What happens in such cases can be very random, it could be a catastrophic failure, or it could appear to work fine, atleast today.

Comment: @PHIfounder: You might like to run the program compiled from  OP's orginal source using Valgrind (http://valgrind.org) and you'll see what is going wrong behind the scene, even if the program might not crash.

Comment: Does Valgrind run on windows? I use gdb.

Comment: @PHIfounder: Do you use MinGW or Cygwin? For MinGW this might help: http://sourceforge.net/p/valgrind4win/wiki/DevelopmentEnvironment/

Comment: MinGW ,thank you very much for the link.An upvote for you.

Answer (score 4):

Following your style, change

```
path = (char **) realloc(path, sizeof(char *));
```

to

```
path = realloc(path, (i+2) * sizeof(char *));
```

This allocates for the *next* loop.  Should you want to reallocate per each loop, it makes more sense to allocate *beforehand* as in:

```
path = realloc(path, (i+1) * sizeof(char *));
path[i] = strdup("TEST");
```

OR

As other say, allocate all your memory up front with `path = malloc(5 * sizeof(char *))`.  Dropping the cast of (char **) is the preferred coding practice.

OR

Allocate all your memory up front with

```
path = calloc(5, sizeof(char *));
```

This have 2 benefits of calloc(num,size) over `malloc(size)`.  The memory is zero filled.  Should the  multiplication of the num * size overflow (obviously not in this case), the `calloc()` still would correctly handle it.

---

Another coding practice thought: using `ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr))` has a nice advantage over `ptr = malloc(sizeof(char *))`.  Should the type of `*ptr` change (even though not likely here), no coding change would be needed in various `malloc()` calls.  (Applies to realloc() and calloc(), too.)

Comment: This is probably what the code was supposed to mean, but it would deserve some explanation.

Comment: Needs `i+2`, after accessing `path[i]`, `path` must already point to at least `i+1` items, or you have UB.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Nice catch on the +2.

Comment: @DanielFischer agreed with you after running the code but can't understand why i+2 is necessary and can't get what is UB.

Comment: The second time in the OP's `for` loop, the assignment `path[1] = strdup("TEST");` occurs.  By this time, `path` needs to be _2_ pointers big.  Thus the realloc() of the previous loop, when `i` was 0, must provide for 2.  In the last & 5th time through the loop, when i = 4, realloc() would make for 6.  path[6] would never be used.  Sooooo, do the reallloc() _before_ the assignment, rather than _afterward_.

Comment: One more thing i need to ask, suppose if i allocated 4bytes of memory using malloc and then later i did realloc by passing in the base address of the memory allocated earlier using malloc and in realloc i specified to allocate 8 bytes of memory. So, now in total i will have 12 bytes of memory or 8 bytes of memory.

Comment: @msatyam 8 bytes. The first 4 are released in the `realloc ()` call.